# Check and Toggle Airplane Mode with Private APIs on iPhone

Tags: iphone, private-methods, airplane-mode

Does anyone know how to check and toggle Airplane mode using the Private APIs? (No, SCNetworkReachability is not good enough, and yes, I'm happy to use private APIs that will potentially break in the future.)

Answer (score 4):

You might find this link interesting:

[iOS 6 Runtime Headers search for "airplane"](https://github.com/search?q=repo%3anst/iOS-Runtime-Headers%20airplane&repo=&langOverride=&start_value=1&type=Code&language=)

Check out the [second hit](https://github.com/nst/iOS-Runtime-Headers/blob/3686717e107fa36a990fac20c30da2da9a25b698/PrivateFrameworks/AppSupport.framework/RadiosPreferences.h):

```
// RadiosPreferences.h

@class <RadiosPreferencesDelegate>;

@interface RadiosPreferences : NSObject  {
    struct __SCPreferences { } *_prefs;
    int _applySkipCount;
    <RadiosPreferencesDelegate> *_delegate;
    BOOL _isCachedAirplaneModeValid;
    BOOL _cachedAirplaneMode;
    BOOL notifyForExternalChangeOnly;
}

@property BOOL airplaneMode;
@property BOOL notifyForExternalChangeOnly;
@property <RadiosPreferencesDelegate> * delegate;


- (void)setAirplaneMode:(BOOL)arg1;
- (id)init;
- (void)setValue:(void*)arg1 forKey:(id)arg2;
- (void)dealloc;
- (void)synchronize;
- (void)setDelegate:(id)arg1;
- (id)delegate;
- (BOOL)airplaneMode;
- (void*)getValueForKey:(id)arg1;
- (void)refresh;
- (void)initializeSCPrefs:(id)arg1;
- (void)notifyTarget:(unsigned int)arg1;
- (void)setCallback:(int (*)())arg1 withContext:(struct { int x1; void *x2; int (*x3)(); int (*x4)(); int (*x5)(); }*)arg2;
- (void)setNotifyForExternalChangeOnly:(BOOL)arg1;
- (BOOL)notifyForExternalChangeOnly;

@end
```

Here's an example of how to use these results (from the readme of that GitHub repo):

```
NSBundle *b = [NSBundle bundleWithPath:@"/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GAIA.framework"];
BOOL success = [b load];

Class SKTelephonyController = NSClassFromString(@"SKTelephonyController");
id tc = [SKTelephonyController sharedInstance];

NSLog(@"-- myPhoneNumber: %@", [tc myPhoneNumber]);
NSLog(@"-- imei: %@", [tc imei]);
```

Comment: Is there one similar for bluetooth?

Comment: @yulz Here's your [search query](https://github.com/search?q=repo%3Anst%2FiOS-Runtime-Headers+bluetooth&repo=&langOverride=&start_value=1&type=Code&language=); here's a [promising result](https://github.com/nst/iOS-Runtime-Headers/blob/3686717e107fa36a990fac20c30da2da9a25b698/PrivateFrameworks/BluetoothManager.framework/BluetoothManager.h).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response, I'll be sure to try it out

Comment: Sweeeeet, thanks! Can't wait to test this out. GAIA.framework??

Comment: That's just a general example of how to use functionality from the runtime headers. Obviously replace that with the framework and methods you're interested in.

Comment: I am not getting how to use above mentioned framework to toggle the airplane mode, i am novice user, can you please explain it in detail...

Comment: Your second code block has absolutely nothing to do with the question, and the private RadiosPreferences APIs. As such, it's confusing.